# For a struct vertex, what's the difference between map[int]vertex and map[int]*vertex?

Tags: go

To define a map from int to struct vertex, should I define `map[int]vertex` or `map[int]*vertex`? Which one is preferred?

I extended Chickencha's code:

```
package main

type vertex struct {
    x, y int 
}

func main() {
    a := make(map[int]vertex)
    b := make(map[int]*vertex)

    v := &vertex{0, 0}
    a[0] = *v
    b[0] = v 

    v.x, v.y = 4, 4
    println(a[0].x, a[0].y, b[0].x, b[0].y)

    //a[0].x = 3 // cannot assign to (a[0]).x
    //a[0].y = 3 // cannot assign to (a[0]).y
    b[0].x = 3 
    b[0].y = 3 
    println(a[0].x, a[0].y, b[0].x, b[0].y)

    u1 := a[0]
    u1.x = 2 
    u1.y = 2 
    u2 := b[0]
    u2.x = 2 
    u2.y = 2 
    println(a[0].x, a[0].y, b[0].x, b[0].y)
}
```

The output:

```
0 0 4 4
0 0 3 3
0 0 2 2
```

From the output, my understanding is, if I want to change the struct member in place, I must use pointer to the struct.
But I'm still not sure the underlying reasons. Especially, why I cannot assign to a[0].x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that `map[int]vertex` stores vertex values and `map[int]*vertex` stores vertex references (pointers). The output of the following program should help illustrate:

```
package main

type vertex struct {
    x, y int
}

func main() {
    a := make(map[int]vertex)
    b := make(map[int]*vertex)

    v := &vertex{0, 0}
    a[0] = *v
    b[0] = v

    v.x, v.y = 4, 4
    println(a[0].x, a[0].y, b[0].x, b[0].y)
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 4 4
```

The vertex stored in b is modified by the `v.x, v.y = 4, 4` line, while the vertex stored in a is not.

Comment: `map[int]vertex` stores a value and `map[int]*vertex` stores a pointer for the map element. In Go, slices, maps, and channels are reference types.

Comment: Right, I guess my wording could've been unclear. I'll edit it so hopefully it says what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is likely to be dependent on how Go maps are implemented. For the current implementation, I would take a look the Go map runtime header, [hashmap.h](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/hashmap.h), and code, [hashmap.c](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/hashmap.c), files. It's also going to depend on how you use the map e.g. what type and volume of activities against the map, key and element data structures, etc.

To update a vector element value in place, read the vector element value from the map, update the element value, write the updated element value to the map. For example

```
package main

type vertex struct {
    x, y int
}

func main() {
    a := make(map[int]vertex)
    a[0] = vertex{0, 0}

    println(a[0].x, a[0].y)
    v0 := a[0]
    v0.x = 1
    a[0] = v0
    println(a[0].x, a[0].y)
}
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 0
```